# Ionic ngForIn unknown property for ion-row

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I am building a component where I would like to iterate over a list and create many items in a list. The public attribute `values` is set. However, I get the error below.

```
Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-item'.
```

The component consist of only this.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let v in values">
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Another issue with the component is that VSCode says none of the `ionic` components are known.
When I show the component it fails.

Comment: This: `<ion-item *ngFor="let v in values">` shoud be `<ion-item *ngFor="let v of values">`. `of` not `in`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the Python stuck in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Update your *ngFor with below code insted of in use of

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let v of values">
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```